# Outlook VBA - Not able to update database

Tags: vba, oracle11g, outlook, adodb, recordset

I am having issues with updating my database. I am using an ADODB recordset. It is giving me this error: ***Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.*** However, the query does produce results as I get one for the variable status. But, it errors out when I get to the .Fields line.

```
newVal= "new value"
sql = "select STATUS FROM NEW_TABLE where ID = '2'"

With rs
    .Open sql, dbs, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    status = rs.GetString
    .Fields("STATUS").Value = newVal
    .Update
    .Close

End With

cnn.Close
```

Comment: What database are you connect to? MS Access? SQL Server? It is very important to mention and tag the db engine. The error is basically saying the query returned no records. Why are you filtering for `ID='2'` if you are trying to add record to table?

Comment: I updated the tag for Oracle DB. I am trying to update the 'status' column where the ID = 2

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, consider using an action append query on the ADODB connection. No need to open the recordset. [ADODB Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676529%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) actually saves changes to deletes, inserts, and updates to records.

APPEND QUERY

```
newVal= "new value"
sql = "INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (ID, Status) VALUES ('2', '" & newValue & "')"
dbs.Execute sql
```

UPDATE QUERY

```
newVal= "new value"
sql = "UPDATE NEW_TABLE SET Status = '" & newValue & "' WHERE ID='2'"
dbs.Execute sql
```